Retaining Wall Water Passthrough
So I have this idea, maybe it is crazy, but can you make a retaining wall that, instead of having water drain behind or under or French drained away... just let the water through it? Why can't I take a block retaining wall, give it a good gravel and sand foundation, make sure there's a foot of gravel behind the wall before, and then set each block with a 1/16 or 1/8 gap left and right so that the water trickles through the wall? If the gap is way smaller than any of the gravel it can't erode.
I want to build up a small 2 or 3 foot retaining wall planter thing around a structure, but it has no gutters so the water will run off into the planted area (different conversation, but what's the best way to take a roof and have no gutters without spoiling the soffits? "Just use gutters" responses need not apply) and so if the planter box area is heavily graded away from the building, and the ground around the planted area is solid 2% graded away for another 10 feet, can the water from the roof pour into the planter area, run off and through the wall, and then through the grass without having issues with water pooling against the foundation?

that flow of water is going to carry sediment with it, working against the purpose of the retaining wall.

Through a foot of gravel?

first, into the gravel, and later, through the gaps in the wall, yes. Eventually they will clog the gravel and/or the gaps, and your retaining wall will again retain water

So then why doesn't this happen in the downward direction? Every guide on retaining walls talks about a gravel bed for drainage as if that'll last forever. Why doesn't erosion go down if it'll go sideways?

Sediment follows water flow, it's unavoidable. You can use very fine mesh to filter out larger particles, like landscape fabric. But anything that can dissolve in water is going to flow with it.

Frost heave.  Does it never freeze where you ?

@SortofDamocles you need to use geotextile at any interface between fine particled material and granular material, e.g. between soil and gravel.

@ Fresh Codemonger - I don't understand your comment.

I'm with you on the "no gutter" front.
We had a similar situation at my condo and the rules do not allow gutters to be installed on the buildings. ( damage control. Yes another conversation)
An expert was hired to figure the drainage set up. He is exceptionally good and we refer to him as "the Water Whisperer."
After making sure the grading from the building was proper he built a short wall, 3 blocks high (24 inches).  A piece of 1 inch PVC pipe was installed at the base of each block at the corners. landscape fabric used and stone was filled over it (about 1 inch river stone).  Another layer of landscape fabric and then backfill of topsoil that new plantings could be placed in.
The plantings were done and mulch added over top.  The system has been working to stop heavy rains from eroding the ground at the base of the building for about 4 years now.  After a heavy rain you can see the water trickle out of the pipes at the bottom of the wall.  There has been no clogging, and the best part is the facia on the roof has remained undamaged as well.

I'd be various curious to understand if anything particular was done to the roof edge to save the wood of the roof parts under the shingles, because everyone I've talked to says that if you don't have gutters, water will somehow get up under the shingles and rot the wood instead of falling off them.
I hadn't thought of using PVC pipes, just gaps, but that's a cool idea, too.

Whomever told you that is confusing the gutters with the drip edge. Gutters take the water away from the foundation but look ugly and take lots of maintenance.

I guess I need smarter friends, because three of them all agreed you gotta-have them gutters. I googled it and found about drip guards and gutter aprons, and gutters and there's a heck of a lot of nuance I was ignorant of.

You must have drip edge, gutters NO...This is what an old roofer told me about gutters,  People think they need gutters, but what they need is a way to control the rain that slides off their roof. Holding it up to and damming it next to the facia only guarantees damage.  Let the roof do its' job and shed the rain.
